# DNN Ajax IE Error

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain, dotnetnuke

I am trying to create a Dotnetnuke module that will get data from a Web Api service and I am trying to hit it from my module it gets an error(access is denied) in the ajax call but only in IE.  In Firefox it works perfectly.  And if it is not in Dotnetnuke a website it works in either Firefox or IE. Here is the ajax I'm having a problem with:

```
var Rep = (function () { 
  var json = null; 

$.support.cors = true; 

$.ajax({ 
type: "GET", 
async: false, 
global: false, 
url: "http://localhost:50611/TestRep.svc/offices/2", 
dataType: "json", 

success: function (data) { 
json = data; 
alert("done"); 
}, 
error: function (jqXHR, testStatus, errorThrown) { 
jqXHR.status + textStatus + errorThrown); 
} 
}); //ajax 


return json; 

});
```

Error message from the ajax(0errorError: Access is denied.)

I also tried XDomainRequest and got the same-ish error (Microsoft JScript runtime error: Access is denied.) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by a syntax error. Take out the extra " before `http` in this line:

```
url: ""http://localhost:50611/TestRep.svc/offices/2",
```

Comment: Sorry I must have added that when posting. It wasn't there in the code.